# Manipular caracteres de elementos de arreglos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

He comenzando a aprender a usar JavaScript, no tengo experiencia en este tipo de lenguajes. Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es reemplazar algunos caracteres de los nombres de los elementos, por ejemplo , el siguiente programa me entrega las 4 frutas, al momento de imprimirlas quisiera reemplazar las `"a" por "4"` y las `"g" por "j"`.

¿Es esto posible en JavaScript?

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard for loop:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: JSON es un formato de transferencia de datos, no "hace" cosas. Para "hacer" cosas usas un lenguaje de programación; por el código que pones supongo que es Javascript...

Comment: copia el código en lugar de una imagen, así facilitas la vida y con gusto la gente copia y trata de reproducir tu pregunta para darte una solución, tenlo presente :D por cierto, bienvenido a SOes

Comment: lo que muestras es un arrays no un JSON.

Comment: Como menciona fwBasic en el comentario anterior, el código incluido en la pregunta es JavaScript y los los nombres de frutas están en un "array" (matriz o arreglo) no en un JSON. Por otro lado, la pregunta no incluye mención de lo buscado/investigado. Si no lo haz hecho aún, revisa [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar los métodos `split()` conjuntamente con `join()` o como indica ***@Dev. Joel***, con: `replace()` pero este ultimo lo hará solo con la primera ocurrencia a menos que uses [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), anexo un ejemplo que muestra las 3 maneras (entre otras) de hacerlo:

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;

fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;
text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

    // con split() + join()
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i].split("a").join("4").split("g").join("j") + "</li>";

    // con replace() ...solo la primera ocurrencia.
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i].replace("a","4").replace("g","j") + "</li>";

    // con replace() + expresiones regulares
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i].replace(/[ag]/g,function(e) {
     return ( e=="a" ) ? "4" : "j";
    }) + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard for loop:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: **No siempre será solo la primera ocurrencia** , se le puede especificar la marca `g(global)` para que tome todas las ocurrencias .`fruits[i].replace(/a/g,'4').replace(/g/g,'j');`

Comment: En el caso que se plantea quise dar una solución básica pero funcional mas que complicarlo con expresiones regulares, pero indudablemente tienes razón.

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede servir, lo que hace es pasar los elementos (`string`) por un `Array.prototype.map()` y reemplazar los caracteres que el regexp identifique.

```js
var fruits, fruitsIn, text, fLen, i;

fruitsIn = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

fruits = fruitsIn.map(function (fruit) {
  return fruit.replace(/[ag]/g, function (character) {
    switch (character) {
      case 'a': return '4'
      case 'g': return 'j'
    }
  })
})

fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p>The best way to loop through an array is using a standard for loop:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```